# Android: Setting for Drawable in Expandable List View

Tags: android, expandablelistview

In my app i have an expandable list view that i want to change the group arrow on expandable listview with another drawables but nothing is displayed.
This is my code, How can i fix it?

```
<ExpandableListView
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:id="@+id/expandableListView"
            android:groupIndicator="@drawable/group_indicator"/>
```

group_indicator.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <item android:state_empty="true" android:drawable="@drawable/arrow_up"></item>
        <item android:state_expanded="true" android:drawable="@drawable/arrow_down"></item>
        <item android:drawable="@drawable/arrow_up"></item>
</selector>
```

ParentActivity.java :

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        final ParentActivity thisActivity = this;
        setContentView(R.layout.backup_list);
        ActionBar actionBar = getSherlock().getActionBar();
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        // get the listview
        expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.expandableListView);
        expListView.setIndicatorBounds(width - GetDipsFromPixel(50), width - GetDipsFromPixel(10));
....
}



 public int GetDipsFromPixel(float pixels)
    {
        // Get the screen's density scale
        final float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        // Convert the dps to pixels, based on density scale
        return (int) (pixels * scale + 0.5f);
    }
```

**EDIT :**

[image]

Comment: Can you post your SS because your code looks fine and it should work.

Comment: @GrlsHu : can you find anything?

Comment: what is width in setIndicatorBounds? try to Log.d.() it

Comment: @pskink: how can i use Log.d() ?

Comment: @pskink : i found that what you say.

Comment: read android.util.Log documentation?

Comment: @pskink: i understood what you said, my drawables are in drawable and drawable-ldpi folders, does it might be the problem?

Comment: what dos logcat say about width variable?